# How do I render a form with JavaScript?

Tags: 8, javascript, ajax

I'm trying to render a Drupal 8 modal dialog form through JavaScript, so it can appear on multiple pages across my site. In the controller class, I create an `AjaxResponse` object with an `openModalDialogCommand` for the modal form. I want to render the modal dialog through JavaScript, so that I can control in which pages it displays.

```
$(document).ready(function() {
  $('body').append('<div id="ao-interstitial-modal"></div>');
  console.log(Drupal);
  jQuery('#ao-interstitial-modal').load('/aao_additions/modal_form');
});
```

This the JavaScript code I write so far, but it renders a textarea in the body tag with the AJAX command object as text inside it.

What do I need to do to render the form as a dialog popup?

Comment: You shouldn't need any JavaScript for that. But please edit your question and try to explain exactly what you are trying to do and why? What form? Where on the page exactly? Do you have any sample use case?

Answer (score 1):

Loading a form via ajax is no different then loading any other page with ajax. The quick answer is that you should create a route to display the form and then call that route via ajax but for a detailed description you should take a look here: https://www.drupal.org/node/2046693